# How to check if a table is locked in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, locking

I have a large report I am running on sql server. It takes several minutes to run. I don't want users clicking run twice. Since i wrap the whole procedure in a transaction, how do I check to see if the table is locked by a transaction? If so I would want to return an error message saying "report generating, please try again in a few  minutes".

How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Better yet, consider [`sp_getapplock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) which is designed for this. Or use [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx)

Otherwise, you'd have to do something with [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) which I'd use only for DBA stuff: not for user defined concurrency.

Comment: SET LOCK_TIMEOUT is the best solution

Answer (score 33):

You can use the [`sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) view, which returns information about the currently active lock manager resources.

Try this

```
 SELECT 
     SessionID = s.Session_id,
     resource_type,   
     DatabaseName = DB_NAME(resource_database_id),
     request_mode,
     request_type,
     login_time,
     host_name,
     program_name,
     client_interface_name,
     login_name,
     nt_domain,
     nt_user_name,
     s.status,
     last_request_start_time,
     last_request_end_time,
     s.logical_reads,
     s.reads,
     request_status,
     request_owner_type,
     objectid,
     dbid,
     a.number,
     a.encrypted ,
     a.blocking_session_id,
     a.text       
 FROM   
     sys.dm_tran_locks l
     JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON l.request_session_id = s.session_id
     LEFT JOIN   
     (
         SELECT  *
         FROM    sys.dm_exec_requests r
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
     ) a ON s.session_id = a.session_id
 WHERE  
     s.session_id > 50
```

Comment: Awesome Query   .

Answer (score 12):

If you are verifying if a lock is applied on a table or not, try the below query.

```
SELECT resource_type, resource_associated_entity_id,
    request_status, request_mode,request_session_id,
    resource_description, o.object_id, o.name, o.type_desc 
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks l, sys.objects o
WHERE l.resource_associated_entity_id = o.object_id
    and resource_database_id = DB_ID()
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but NONE of the other answers produced anything for me. Just this answer...

Answer (score 5):

**sys.dm_tran_locks**  contains the locking information of the sessions

If you want to know a specific table is locked or not, you can use the following query

```
SELECT 
 * 
from 
 sys.dm_tran_locks 
where 
  resource_associated_entity_id = object_id('schemaname.tablename')
```

if you are interested in finding both login name of the user and the query being run

```
SELECT
 DB_NAME(resource_database_id)
 , s.original_login_name
 , s.status
 , s.program_name
 , s.host_name
 , (select text from sys.dm_exec_sql_text(exrequests.sql_handle))
 ,*
from
  sys.dm_tran_locks dbl
     JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON dbl.request_session_id = s.session_id
  INNER JOIN  sys.dm_exec_requests exrequests on dbl.request_session_id = exrequests.session_id
where
 DB_NAME(dbl.resource_database_id) = 'dbname'
```

For more infomraton [locking query](https://mysoftwareexperience.blogspot.in/2017/06/finding-locking-queries.html)

More infor about [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
db_name(rsc_dbid) AS 'DATABASE_NAME',
case rsc_type when 1 then 'null'
              when 2 then 'DATABASE' 
              WHEN 3 THEN 'FILE'
              WHEN 4 THEN 'INDEX'
              WHEN 5 THEN 'TABLE'
              WHEN 6 THEN 'PAGE'
              WHEN 7 THEN 'KEY'
              WHEN 8 THEN 'EXTEND'
              WHEN 9 THEN 'RID ( ROW ID)'
              WHEN 10 THEN 'APPLICATION' end  AS 'REQUEST_TYPE',

CASE req_ownertype WHEN 1 THEN 'TRANSACTION'
                   WHEN 2 THEN 'CURSOR'
                   WHEN 3 THEN 'SESSION'
                   WHEN 4 THEN 'ExSESSION' END AS 'REQUEST_OWNERTYPE',

OBJECT_NAME(rsc_objid ,rsc_dbid) AS 'OBJECT_NAME', 
PROCESS.HOSTNAME , 
PROCESS.program_name , 
PROCESS.nt_domain , 
PROCESS.nt_username , 
PROCESS.program_name ,
SQLTEXT.text 
FROM sys.syslockinfo LOCK JOIN 
     sys.sysprocesses PROCESS
  ON LOCK.req_spid = PROCESS.spid
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(PROCESS.SQL_HANDLE) SQLTEXT
```

Answer (score -2):

The simplest way to check if a table is locked is by updating a field in that table. If the table is locked you will get an error message similar to this:

> ERROR 1099 (HY000): Table 'accounts' was locked with a READ lock and can't be updated
> MariaDB [test]>

So just create an 'UPDATE query (or another query that does an operation) to the table you want to check and see if you get the error message above.

Have you ever forgotten to lock the door to your house? the only way to check if the door is LOCKED is by you manually checking if the door opens.. that's the best way i can describe it.