# SQL Server Delete Statement Timing Out

Tags: sql-server

I have a process that runs during our businesses off hours. The process occasionally fails on a delete statement. The delete statement is executed through Entity Framework (I don't know if that's important or not) and there is cascade deleting that occurs also.

The error we get is the following: Timeout expired.

> The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation
>   or the server is not responding.  The statement has been terminated.

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this. I discovered that we have another process running at the same time that selects data from a view over the same files that the delete is occurring on. Can a read on this view "block" the delete?

```
 public void DeletePolicySegments(IList<int> segmentIds)
    {
        using (Models.PolicyContainer context = new Models.PolicyContainer())
        {
            if (segmentIds != null && segmentIds.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var segmentId in segmentIds)
                {
                    var x = context.PolicySegments.Where(t => t.SegmentId == segmentId).Single();
                    context.PolicySegments.DeleteObject(x);
                }
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

It should only be deleting 2-4 "segments" per each call of "DeletePolicySegments".

Comment: Can you give us the DELETE code?

Comment: Check to see if the tables are locked... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511675/how-to-check-if-a-table-is-locked-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the read can block a delete.

However, it could also be the cascading delete that is causing this.

We ran into the exact same issue, and it turns out the issue wasn't with the table we were deleting from (Table A), but the table that had a foreign key reference to it (Table B).

In Table B, we didn't have an index on the field that was a foreign key to Table A.  So for every record being deleted from Table A, Table B had to be sequentially scanned to look for foreign key constraints.  When we would try to delete around 1000 records from Table A at once, the query would time out.

Once we added an index to the field in Table B, the DELETE on Table A went from taking 10 minutes to running instantaneously.

Comment: We've checked all our cascade deletes and we have indexes on all those foreign keys.

Comment: @AWeim - Not just cascading deletes - any kind of foreign key constraint (ON DELETE NO ACTION, etc.).

Comment: Are you saying we need indexes for all FK contraints?

Comment: All FK constraints from other tables to the table in which the DELETE is happening.

Comment: I'm in the process of running the tunning advisor to see what additional indexes are recommended.